# Does one need to put aria-label on a form submit button?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

As the title says, for accessibility we need to put a aria-label on elements where label text is not visible or not present, for example a dismiss button with only an "X".

I take it as if a button has text, then the aria-label won't be needed, for example:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

But what about:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Does the input submit button need an aria-label?

Comment: As @Fleshgrinder already answered, it wouldn't be needed with `value="Submit"` if this readable text is OK. Just wanted to add that it's exactly the same with `<input src="path/name.ext" type="image" alt="Submit">`. And probably `<input type="button" value="Submit"/>` (never used the latter though)

Comment: @FelipeAls in your first example you meant <img> instead of <input>?

Comment: No, `input` :) `image` is another type that at least was used with lesser IEs (no gradients, no ... you relied a lot on images). Visually the same result could be achieved with an `img` into a `button`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends, both of your examples wouldn’t need it per se, because there is visible (and readable) text. If you want to describe the element in greater detail you’d use the `title` attribute before you use the `aria-label` attribute; [as stated in the standard text](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#aria-label).

```
<button title="Continue here after you’ve filled out all form elements">Submit</button>

<input title="Continue here after you’ve filled out all form elements" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

The thingy with the closing `x` is somewhat different, because if I say to you “x” what do you think? That’s why we want to help the screen readers (or other technology). But a `title` attribute would still be better and create a visible tooltip for all users.

```
<a href="/" title="Close this foo."><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></a>
```

---

ARIA navigation example that validates (see comments).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>ARIA Example</title></head><body>
<!--
More HTML that makes up your document
-->
<!--
We apply the role navigation on the nav element to help older browsers, of course
the nav element already has the ARIA meaning, but it doesn't hurt anyone to make
sure that all browsers understand it
-->   
<nav role="navigation">
    <!--
    Omit title from display but not from e.g. screen readers see h5bp.com/v or
    h5bp.com/p
    -->
    <h2 class="visuallyhidden">Main Navigation</h2>
    <ul role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/" role="menuitem">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!--
More HTML that makes up your document
-->
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your response. Speaking of using "title", that's actually a point that I completely missed.

Comment: Always try to use pure HTML solutions. This might be from great interest to you: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-aria-in-html-20130214/#recommendations-table

Comment: The speak CSS isn't supported by any popular screen reader, you'd be better putting that in a sub-element with aria-prentation: <a href="/" title="Close."><span role="presentation">x</span></a> Also, try and avoid 'click to'. Start with the keyword (close), and perhaps use the term "select", but remember not everyone is using a mouse.

Comment: Good point, I'll update my answer. I used `aria-hidden` because it has wide support.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder thanks, that table is really useful. However, I find it confusing as when to use native HTML and when to add ARIA tags. For example do I need to add aria-labelledby to an input field to point it towards the label? Even if the label already has a "for" attribute?

Comment: @Fleshgrinder Or is ARIA more for things that's custom made so the implied semantics doesn't match the actual semantics? If that's the case I would assume ARIA tags should only be used very occasionally...

Comment: If you have an identifying label then there's no need for ARIA. It's important to use ARIA if the normal semantic doesn't allow the user agent any clue of what's going on. Best usage example is a navigation and I extended my answer to include an example.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder thanks for your follow up, but 2 things regarding your added example: 1). This probably won't affect anything but I think you shouldn't use h2 straightaway without a higher level heading before that; 2). If you have a visually hidden heading, why not use "aria-label" on the <nav> element?

Comment: Haha, of course there would be an `h1` somewhere on the page but hopefully not for the main navigation. I only included the doctype and head for the W3Validator. `nav` is a section in HTML5 and the first heading within a section is the heading for the complete section. Absolutely no need for a `aria-label` in this case.

Comment: And yes, you could use an `h1` if you'd like to use headings as intended in the new HTML5 standard from the W3C. No clue how the WhatWG guys see this. Personally I still stick to the old rules where we have proper hierarchy in our headings and not spreading `h1`s all over the documents.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41053/discussion-between-xavier-ex-and-fleshgrinder)

Comment: NB: title attribute is not consistently supported by screenreader software. It sometimes overrides the value of alt attributes, and in other cases is skipped altogether. Probably best to avoid using it. If you need a visual tooltip, make one using data- attributes and CSS instead.

Comment: You can't support every broken client, it's best to find a mediocrity between the real standard and the broken clients out there. The `title`-attribute is the correct attribute for additional information since the beginning of HTML.